# Как добавить в корзину свойства Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Привет всем. Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить в корзину свойства, например: я хочу заранее написать текст АКЦИЯ + ПОДАРОК, обычно в catalog.element с этим не было проблем, там я делал с помощью вот такого кода

```
<?if($arResult['PROPERTIES']['ACTION_GIFT']['VALUE']){ ?> Тут текст <?}?>'
```

читал устаревший мануал 2011, там очень много действий, у меня Битрикс 2015 года. Думаю до этого времени они внесли кое-какие поправки по этому компоненту basket.basket. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решения данной задачи, нужно было через var_dump($arItem) проверить данные переменной $arItem

```
    <?if($arItem['PROPERTY_ACTION_CHECKBOX_VALUE'] == "Y"){?>
            <div>АКЦИОННЫЙ ТОВАР <span>+ ПОДАРОК</span></div>
    <?}?>
```

Это код работает так: Если этот товар входит в акцию, то показать надпись.

Свойство которые я добавлял в инфоблоке ACTION_CHECKBOX

Перед этим автоматом добавляет надпись PROPERTY_ НАЗВАНИЯ ВАШЕГО СВОЙСТВА _VALUE